# MVCMailer SendAsync and deleting attachments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mailmessage, sendasync, mvcmailer

I'm having trouble getting MVCMailer to delete attachments after sending an email asynchronously.

I can't figure out what to do to dispose of the message to free up processes attached to the message attachments.

Following the instructions [here](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)....

```
    private IUserMailer userMailer = new UserMailer();

    public IUserMailer UserMailer
    {
        get { return this.userMailer; }
        set { this.userMailer = value; }
    }


      using (SmtpClientWrapper client = new SmtpClientWrapper())
        {
            client.SendCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled)
                {
                    // Handle Error
                }

                //Use e.UserState

                //?? How can I use the userstate?? There are no
                // instructions??

                // Delete the saved attachments now. 
                // This will not work since the mailmessage process 
                // is still attached.
                Parallel.ForEach(imageList, image =>
                {

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(image))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(image);
                    }

                });

            };

            // SendAsync() extension method: using Mvc.Mailer
            // farm is my model imageList is a list of file locations for the 
            // uploaded attachments
          UserMailer.Submission(farm, imageList).SendAsync("user state object",
                                                            client);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run break the SmtpClientWrapper out of the using statement and call dispose on it manually just before you clean-up the attachment.

Comment: I'm adding my own answer just to demonstrate what I wrote but as it was based upon this suggestion I will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

To show what my successful solution was:

```
        MailMessage message = UserMailer.Submission(farm, imageList);

        SmtpClientWrapper client = new SmtpClientWrapper();

        client.SendCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Handle Error
            }

            if (message != null)
            {
                message.Attachments.Dispose();
                message.Dispose();

                // Delete the saved attachments now
                Parallel.ForEach(imageList, image =>
                {

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(image))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(image);
                    }

                });

            }

            client.Dispose();

        };

        // SendAsync() extension method: using Mvc.Mailer
        message.SendAsync("farm message", client);
```